# get a percentage of daily errors

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i have 1 table with 2 columns i work with (time,status)
i select a certain day with  `date_trunc()` in the time column and apply condition `where status = '404 NOT FOUND'`

and divide that with the daily count
to get a percentage of daily errors

```
status has 2 values 404 NOT FOUND and 200 OK
--------------------------------------------
```

**i wanna get the daily error percentage**

i tried :
`select case when status = '404 NOT FOUND' then count(time) END / count(time) from log group by date_trunc('day',time);`
but got an error i get error column "log.status" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: `COUNT` needs to be used with a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: how to put it in a group by ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select date_trunc('day', time) as dte,
       avg(case when status <> '200 OK' then 1.0 else 0 end) as daily_rate
from log l
group by dte;
```

In Postgres, this can further be shortened to:

```
select date_trunc('day', time) as dte,
       avg( (status <> '200 OK')::int ) as daily_rate
from log l
group by dte;
```

Comment: can you explain it to me ? only line 2 and 3

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT days, (ERROR*1.0/TOTAL)*100.0 Percentage FROM
(select date_trunc('day',time) days,
    COUNT(case when status = '404 NOT FOUND' 
                   then 1 ELSE NULL END) ERROR,
    COUNT(1) TOTAL
from log
group by date_trunc('day',time)) A;
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 3:                    then 1 ELSE NULL) ERROR

Comment: Try again. Fixed some typos.

Comment: returns ?column? with 31 zeros

Comment: Multiplied by 1.0 to convert to decimal. This should give better results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/84e2b8/9

Comment: as u know i wanna select time and error/total where error/total >1

Comment: `as u know`? Why would I know that? Also, error/total cannot be > 1 so you will not get any results.

Comment: i get one result only  2.26268624680272595600 that's above 1
sorry for as u know :)

Comment: So that's the answer. 2.26% of the logs have 404 error. You can format number to get the precision you need. You can change the columns you are selecting to get the date or time as you need.

Comment: i just want to use this db as it is with just one query to answer it

Comment: Not sure what that means. There is no expected result in your question. Trying to guess what you need and you commenting that it is not working is not the best way to do things. Update your question with what you need and then let me know how the result from the query is different from what you need and I'll take a look.